# Tweak code-completion in JetBrains product

Tags: ide, editor, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-completion

How can I make JetBrains write code instead of me?

For example, in WebStorm I can type `fori` and press `Enter` and this will provide me with a template for a `for` loop.

Now I would like to have my own commands for my own code. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **"Live Templates"**.

Yes, you can create your own snippets / override bundled ones: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Live Templates`.

This how-to is made for PhpStorm, but it's the same for all languages/IDEs:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm